# How to get code coverage report in PyCharm for Python project

Tags: python, pycharm, code-coverage

I have created a simple addition method in python like 
[main.py]

```
class Calculator:

    def sum(self,a,b):
        return a+b
```

And I have written test case in [test.py]

```
from unittest import Testcase
from main import Calculator

class TestCalculator(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.calc=Calculator()

    def test_sum(self):
        answer=self.cals.sum(2,4)
        self.assertEqual(answer,6)
```

Now I want to check code coverage of this code. I am not getting how to get the coverage report in PyCharm IDE. Anyone, please guide if you know how to get the code coverage of the whole project

Comment: Do you use PyCharm Community or Professional? As far as I know, code coverage is a feature from PyCharm Professional. See: https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html

Comment: yes, I am using the community version.

Comment: Than you need to do it as in Rickys answer manually - the community edition has no integrated IDE support for code coverage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just use [Coverage.py](https://coverage.readthedocs.io/en/v4.5.x/).
Just `pip install coverage` and add a main method on your test.py or main.py and run it.

For example, add to test.py,

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

And run on terminal,

```
coverage test.py
```

Comment: But with this, I am able to test a file at a time but not the coverage report of the whole project, if I am having 2 files test1.py and test2.py.

Answer (score 1):

You can set up a shell script and run it with a configuration.

For example, assuming a project structure like this...

```
/project
  /src
    main.py
  /test
    test_something.py
```

...this shell script will run all the tests in the `/test` directory against the source files in the `/src` directory and open a browser with the HTML results:

```
# contents of test_coverage.sh
coverage erase
coverage run --source=./src -m unittest discover ./test
coverage report -m
coverage html
open ./htmlcov/index.html
```

This script is written for Mac using unittest, but you can modify it for whatever OS and test runner you're using. Of course, you can also modify it to run whatever commands you want. For example, if you don't want to generate or open the HTML results, just remove the last two lines. If your project structure looks different, modify the `--source=./src` and `./test` arguments for the `coverage run` command.

This shell script should be run from the root `/project` folder. Make sure import statements in your test_*.py files are relative to that folder. This can easily be overlooked in PyCharm since source directories may be added to PYTHONPATH for you.

Save the shell script as `test_coverage.sh` (or whatever you want to name it) and put it in the root `/project` folder. Then add a Shell Script run configuration in PyCharm with the script path to that file.

[PyCharm Run Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rrARB.png)

When you run the configuration in PyCharm, you should get a report in the terminal and your default browser should open the HTML report (assuming you use the commands above).